# Switch player in tictactoe

Tags: swift3, xcode8

This code is not my own, I followed a youtube video [linked here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIPiMs_jtco&t=223s).

I had an issue with the following code, and have it narrowed down to a specific portion and problem.

First off here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var activePlayer = 1 // cross
var gameState = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    if (gameState[sender.tag] == 0)
    {
        gameState[sender.tag] = activePlayer

        if (activePlayer == 1)
        {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Cross.png"), for: UIControlState())
            activePlayer = 2
        }
        else
        {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Nought.png"), for: UIControlState())
            activePlayer = 1
        }
    }

}
```

The primary issue is that I don't understand the gameState[sender.tag] part. When I run the program, the first click on any of the buttons I have does nothing, and the following click places a cross.png as desired.
After the first cross is placed, clicking produces nothing. The cross doesn't change, nor do any of the blank buttons get turned into crosses or naughts.

In the video tutorial, he instructs to add "-1" at the end of [sender.tag] like this: gameState[sender.tag-1] however, doing this results in an error when I attempt to click on a button when the program is ran. Thusly I removed that portion and the program runs, but the aforementioned situation arises.

I am very new to coding in general, only having completed an intro to C++ course at community college, and now learning Swift 3 as a hobby, so I may be missing some fundamental information that could easily explain this situation.

Thank you to the community in advance for putting up with the potential of this situation being based solely on my ignorance, I have tried to learn about sender.tag, and other things for several days now to no avail. I hope I can learn from this situation and appreciate any information!

Comment: I did not watch the video. But judging from the code you have to assign *tags* (1...9) to all buttons in the Storyboard editor.

Comment: The tutorial never went through that step, and it simply works for him, but he does make mention that the "-1" that he adds is to coincide with the array since arrays start at 0... so idk if he has some option that automatically numbers the buttons or something, but I have never assigned tags to buttons, so I will look into how to do that and get back to you... it seems as if it will work given what I have discovered so far. Thank you for the information.

Comment: It works perfectly after adding tags to the buttons. The video never went through that step... is there some kind of option in Xcode that auto assigns tags to newly created buttons, or something?
I had to add "-1" back to the end of sender.tag in order to match the array set, but now it works perfect. Thanks so much for the information.

Comment: I believe also you should not use `for: UIControlState()` when you set the images.  Rather use a specific control state, e.g. `for: .normal`.

Comment: In the video approx at 4:20: "We are going to give each button a tag ...".

Answer (score 0):

Martin R. answered OP's problem in the comments (the `UIButton` tags were not initialized).  I'd like to elaborate on tags a bit in the hope it will be helpful.

A tag in iOS/OS X programming is simply an integer identifier assigned to a view.  It is totally up to you whether you use them or not.  Unset tags default to zero.

`UIControl`s and all of their subclasses (including `UIButton`s) use a target-action design pattern.  This pattern works by assigning to the control a method (the action) that is called on a particular object (the target) when a user interacts with the control.  Different action methods can be assigned for each type of interaction a control supports (for example, a touch-down action on a button could be distinguished from a touch-up action).

When an action method is called, it receives as its first parameter the `UIControl` instance for which the interaction happened.  This parameter is by convention called the `sender` (which makes sense, since the control is "sending" a notification that some interaction occurred).

Now consider the nine `UIButton`s in a tic-tac-toe grid.  Since all the buttons have the same on-tap behavior, it is convenient to have them each  call the same action method on the view controller.  In OP's question, the action method is literally a function called `action(_ sender:)` (better would be something more descriptive, such as `squareTapped(_ sender: UIButton)`, but I digress).

If the buttons didn't all call the same action method, you'd have to contend with a nightmare of functions like `upperLeftCornerTapped()`, `upperMiddleTapped()`, etc., all of which would do the same thing.  That's very ugly from both a design and maintenance perspective.

But this begs the question: since all the buttons call the *same* action method, how do we distinguish *which* button was actually tapped?  This is where the tag comes in.  When the buttons are setup, we assign each one a unique integer identifier.

Since by default a tag is zero, it is imperative to use non-zero tag values so we are guaranteed the view we identify by tag is one we explicitly consider valid.

As a matter of both convenience and practicality, the button indices start at 1 and go through 9.  This gives us a way to directly associate each button with a game-state variable.  In this case, `tag - 1` is used to get a zero-based index into the mutable `gameState` array.